# How To Map Two Columns from One Dataset with One Column from Another Dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two datasets:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id1': 'AAA ABC ACD ADE AEE AFG'.split(),
                   'id2': 'BBB BBC BCD BDE BEE BFG'.split(),})

print(df1)

   id1  id2
0  AAA  BBB
1  ABC  BBC
2  ACD  BCD
3  ADE  BDE
4  AEE  BEE
5  AFG  BFG

-----------

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'student_id': 'ABC BBB AAA DEF AEE BEE'.split(),
                    'center': '11 22 33 44 55 66'.split()})

print(df2)

  student_id center
0        ABC     11
1        BBB     22
2        AAA     33
3        DEF     44
4        AEE     55
5        BEE     66
```

I need to map both `id1` and `id2` columns from dataset 1 with `student_id` column of dataset 2. Then keep only those `id1` and `id2` columns, if both are present in the `student_id` column. Finally, get their mapped values from dataset 2 as separate columns, respectively.

I'm trying the following script and getting the desired output for my example:

```
map1 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='id1', right_on='student_id').drop(columns=['id2'])
map2 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='id2', right_on='student_id')
map1.merge(map2, on='id1')
```

However, it's neither scaling nor giving the right output when the dataset is huge. For example, with `map1` length of 100,000 rows and `map2` with 70,000 rows, the final length after joining both is close to 1 million. I tried to set `id1` as index for both the mapping datasets and join them, but it didn't scale, too!

*Desired Output*

```
   id1  id2 student_id1 center_1 student_id2 center_2
0  AAA  BBB         AAA       33         BBB       22 # Both AAA, BBB present from dataset 1, with respective values from dataset 2
1  AEE  BEE         AEE       55         BEE       66 # Both AEE, BEE present from dataset 1, with respective values from dataset 2
```

What would be the better ways to do that? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to merge df1 and df2 like you did, and then merge df2 onto the result, just on a different column (id2 instead of id1) like this

```
map1 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='id1', right_on='student_id')
map2 = map1.merge(df2, left_on='id2', right_on='student_id', suffixes=['_1', '_2'])
```

This should produce the correct answer and only uses two merges instead of three for scalability.